# Triggering action if ONE specific file changes on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Is there a way to trigger an action in Microsoft Flow (Power Automate) when just one specific file in SharePoint gets modified? At the moment I have the situation that 6 files are updated at once, so the same action is triggered 6 times in a row.

I use the trigger "When an item is created or modified". There I can only adjust the SharePoint site name and the list (library) of files to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your settings are set in a way the flow don't run in parallel.

In essence, you may want to limit the concurrence of the flow so it will run just once at a time.

1) First go to the settings

[image]

2) Limit the paralellism. If you just want to work on the first item then click turn on `Split On` which will yield a single file.

[image]

You can check [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/TIPS-quot-Split-On-quot-turn-off-for-Twitter-trigger-quot-When-a/td-p/48968) for more details.